# fs.readdir returns undefined when called inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to write a function that takes a path and returns all the files inside that directory.

When I do this:

```
function getDirectories(path) {
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    } else {
      return content;
    }
  });
}

console.log(getDirectories('./XML/'));
```

I get `undefined` in the console.

But when I do this:

```
function getDirectories(path) {
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    } else {
      console.log(content);
    }
  });
}
```

I get the expected array with file names as strings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its because readdir is async - try using `fs.readdirSync`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fs.readdir is async use this :

```
function getDirectories(path, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, content) {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        callback(null, content)
    })
}

getDirectories('./XML', function (err, content) {
    console.log(content)
})
```

Comment: this also returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using fs.readdirSync

```
function getDirectories(path) {
  fs.readdirSync(path, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    } else {
      return content;
    }
  });
}
```

Should work